# 3D surface plot from series of x,y data

Tags: plot, 3d, series

I want to plot a 3D surface plot. My data structure is the following: N files of two-column x,y data (27 row information header), where x is always equally between all datasets, only y varies. In this case I want my y from the dataset to be my z-axis in the 3D plot. X would stay x and y should be an equally spaced number (e.g. 0.5) for every N dataset.

I tried to first concat all files into a large data frame with indexed columns, which works but I don't know how to proceed, or if there is a smarter way to tackle this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import glob   

dataname = "test"
path = "iq/"

all_files = glob.glob("iq/*.iq")

iqdata = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=27, delim_whitespace=True, names=['Q', 'iq'])
    iq = df['iq']
    iqdata.append(iq)


frame = pd.concat(iqdata, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

df_x = pd.read_csv('iq/dataset_0001.iq', index_col=None, header=27, delim_whitespace=True, names=['Q', 'iq'])

frame = pd.concat([df_x, frame], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

frame.to_csv(path + dataname + ".csv", index=False)
```

Any ideas how to smartly improve this and get an 3D surface (e.g. with matplotlib) out of this?

Comment: "x is always equally between all dataset": what do you mean ?

Comment: it means that for every x,y dataset, x has always the same values for example: dataset1: x = 0,1,2 y = 10,20,30 ; dataset2: x = 0,1,2 y = 50,10,30

Comment: Can't you collect the datasets in a single matrix ?

Comment: I updated the code. I now get a datafile where: 1st column is x-axis, 1st row is y-axis and the values in this matrix should be the z-axis.

Comment: Excel can plot that.